# IP based authorization policy with Attributes

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I'm trying to secure a REST API based on the client IP.

Imagine a blog application with these request examples:

```
/post/list               // Everyone     should see the posts
/post/create             // Only Authors should create a post
/post/update/42          // Only Authors should update a post
/post/delete/42          // Only Admins  should delete a post
/comment/42/list         // Everyone     should see a post's comments
/comment/42/create       // Everyone     should create a comment
/comment/42/delete/1337  // Only Admins  should delete a comment
```

IP whitelists defined in **appsettings.json**:

```json
"IpSecurity": {
  "Author": "123.456.789.43,123.456.789.44",
  "Admin": "123.456.789.42"
}
```

Here are action examples with the according `RequireRole` attributes I'd like to implement:

```cs
[HttpGet("post/list")]
public List<Post> List()
// ...

[RequireRole("Author")]
[HttpGet("post/create")]
public StandardResponse Create([FromBody]Post post)
// ...

[RequireRole("Admin")]
[HttpGet("post/delete/{id}")]
public StandardResponse Delete(int id)
// ...
```

Defined injectable from **Startup**

```cs
var IpSecurity = Configuration.GetSection("IpSecurity");
services.Configure<IpSecurityConfig>(IpSecurity);
```

Does it sound like a good idea ?

Should I do a custom authorization policy, a middleware and/or a filter for that ?

How would I implement the `RequireRole` attribute ?

---

[This](http://www.henrihietala.fi/limit-access-to-your-azure-web-app-by-ip-address-asp-net-core/) gives an idea of how to implement an IP whitelist but since a middleware does not have access to the contextual action, I can't use attributes to define my requirements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that looks good not least because it looks easy understand at a glance.

One comment I would offer is that using the term "Role" for this might confuse your successors. Call it "MachineRole" instead? (And, for the same reason, don't use the `[Authorize(Roles="..."]`)

Implementation in AspNetCore looks to me a little more complex that it was under MVC4, something like this in the usual methods in `Startup.cs` :

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //after services.AddMvc() :

    services.AddAuthorization(o => { o.AddPolicy(MachineRole.AuthorMachine, p => p.RequireClaim(nameof(MachineRole), MachineRole.AuthorMachine));  });
    services.AddAuthorization(o => { o.AddPolicy(MachineRole.AdminMachine,  p => p.RequireClaim(nameof(MachineRole), MachineRole.AdminMachine)); });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // ...

    app.UseClaimsTransformation( AddMachineRoleClaims );

    // app.UseMvc( ... );
    // ...etc...
}

public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> AddMachineRoleClaims(ClaimsTransformationContext ctx)
{
    var connectionRemoteIpAddress = ctx.Context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.MapToIPv4();
    if (Configuration.GetSection("IpSecurity")["Author"].Contains(connectionRemoteIpAddress.ToString()))
    {
        ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(nameof(MachineRole), MachineRole.AuthorMachine) }));
    }
    if (Configuration.GetSection("IpSecurity")["Admin"].Contains(connectionRemoteIpAddress.ToString()))
    {
        ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim( nameof(MachineRole), MachineRole.AdminMachine) }));
    }

    return Task.FromResult(ctx.Principal);
}

public static class MachineRole
{
    public const string AuthorMachine = "AuthorMachine";
    public const string AdminMachine = "AdminMachine";
}
```

and then you can use

```cs
[Authorize(Policy = MachineRole.AdminMachine)]
```

Comment: I agree with you about the confusing `Role` term. I'll try your solution.

Comment: I tried with a `[Authorize(Policy = ...)]` defined on a controller action but with an empty `AddIpAddressClaims()`, it's always passing without any error. Shouldn't it return a unauthorized response ?

Comment: I had to `AddAuthorization()` since I'm using `AddMvcCore()` in `ConfigureServices()`. However I finaly used a [Custom Policy-Based Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies) since I find there is too much repetition with Claims based. Also I didn't need the Authentication framework

Comment: In a hurry I left a typo (now fixed) in the code which broke it: `RequireClaim(XXX)` should have been `RequireClaim(IPAddressClaim.Type, XXX)`

Comment: I agree, it's not clear that Claims-based is any simpler than custom policy. I found `UseClaimsTransformation()` too tempting to ignore though: a hook that lets you read the `HttpContext` and then add claims based on it seemed just the thing. It would be be more attractive if there was a `[Authorize(Claim=)]` syntax

Answer (score 1):

I was sufficiently irritated by the fact that this is not simple, and in particular not a simple as it was in MVC4 that I've done https://github.com/chrisfcarroll/RequireClaimAttributeAspNetCore to make it possible to write:

```
    [RequireClaim("ClaimType",Value = "RequiredValue")]
    public IActionResult Action(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've thought about the implications of IP based authorization -- such that they can be spoofed, and requests make it **very** deep into your stack before being rejected...

I'd suggest creating a middleware that assigns claims, or at the very least sets the identity (so the user is authenticated). And then use either claims (which you've assigned to the identity in the middleware) or authorization policies (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies). You could then reject each request based on the IPs associated with a policy:

```
[Authorize(Policy="AuthorIp")]
[HttpGet("post/create")]
public StandardResponse Create([FromBody]Post post)
```

Comment: I know that an IP can be spoofed, I'm more looking for a way to partition my API rather than really securing it actually, otherwise I guess I'd have relied on an OAuth provider. Do you think it would be so deep in the request pipeline ? Isn't it as deep as `[Authorize()]` would be ?

Comment: You're right it will get just as deep. How does "blocking" endpoints based on IP help with partioning? Do the APIs behave differently depending on who's calling them? As for adding a custom authentication scheme, see https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/AuthenticationServiceCollectionExtensions.cs (and other parts of this repo)

Comment: But IP based restrictions are common -- AWS etc offer it; I've worked with 3 companies in financial services that used it, including for connection to a credit card payment provider. It isn't a total security solution but it's certainly a *part* of a solution